# Save image on RAM and work on it using ImageMagick

Tags: php, html, image-processing, imagemagick, gd

I am working on a project where the client can create dynamic image by merging different layers (images) into single image and then show that generated image to client. Currently my code is something like this

```
$output = uniqid().'.jpg';
exec('convert -size 600x800 xc:white '.$output);
$layers = array(//array of about hundreds of PNG images);
foreach($layers as $key => $singleLayer)
{
    $layerIs = $singleLayer['image'];
    $positionsXY = explode(',', $singleLayer['xy']);
    exec('composite -geometry  +'.$positionsXY[0].'+'.$positionsXY[1].' '.$layerIs.' '.$output.' '.$output);
}
$base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($output));
unlink($output);
return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$base64;
```

In my above code, I am generating a white background image and then merging multiple PNG images on it these images are more than 100. While also saving this image every time a single layer is merged and then output the final image to client after deleting the generated image. This all takes about 15 seconds to do.

So, My Question is if ImageMagick has an option which can allow me to save image on ram instead of saving image on harddisk which in turn can speed up my processing?

Although I found this http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20295 but could not understand much of it that how can I implement it.

Comment: You could try with the readImageBlob function of image magick: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimageblob.php and use the `__toString` method of the image magick object to output the image into a variable.

Comment: @Jite I am no wise in ImageMagick. If you don't mind can you elaborate with little code so I can understand it better. And please note that I am using exec() command to work with ImageMagick not PHP Procedural language. So using variable in that would creates some confusion :(

Comment: I would start by recommend using the php extension for imagemagick. Is that possible? Check your `phpinfo()` and see if its installed. Depending on the answer, I'll try give you some further explanation.

Comment: @Jite Yes it is installed as I have VPS and I have installed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to use ImageMagick in php is to use the [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) extension & class. I would not recommend using the exec function for it.

So first off, converting the image and store it in a variable.
You say you are not used to variabled, but by your code it seems like you are, you might just not know it.
For example, your `$output` is a variabe. The variable contains the image after the output is made (if it succeeds).

Now, I'm not 100% sure what your layers array contains, if its images or paths to images, but I expect that its paths, so I'll go with that assumption.

Your first `exec` call does a convert, I don't think that is nessesery, cause you have no input, all you need is a "white image" from what I can see.
To do that, create a new image object with and create a new image which is the correct size and bg color:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(600, 800, "white");
```

You then loop through the layers as you do, but instead of exec you use the imagemagick image you created above:

```
foreach($layers as $key => $singleLayer) {
    $layerIs = $singleLayer['image'];
    $positionsXY = explode(',', $singleLayer['xy']);
    // Each loop should load the image into a new imagemagick object, but we release it when the scope is exited.
    $layer = new IMagick($layerIs);
    $image->compositeImage($layer, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $positionsXY[0], $positionsXY[1]);
}
```

When the loop is complete, the `$image` variable will contain the composited image, which you can return as you wish.

```
$image->setImageFormat('jpg');
return "data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64_encode($image)}";
```

*Note: Code is not tested and written directly in browser. So it might need to be rewritten!*

Comment: Great! Jite your code is working great. But Why it isn't making any difference in terms of performance. It is taking the same 15 seconds to complete processing.

Comment: I would think that the real bottleneck is the loading of the 100'ds of layers to use in the composition of the image. I'm not sure how much that is possible to optimise, possibly by using smaller images or fewer images maybe, but it depends a lot on how they are used. Image manipulation is usually quite heavy work, so it might take some time however you go about with it.

Comment: If you feel that the answer answered the question, feel free to mark it as correct and/or up-vote it!

Comment: Hmmm you are right Jite. Thanks for your kind support.

Comment: Any time. Good luck with the project! :)

Comment: Jite how can we set quality for our generated image? I tried $image->setCompressionQuality(50); before base64_encode() but that is not working

Comment: I think you need to use both that and marking it as jpeg, like: `$img->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
$img->setImageCompressionQuality(50); `

Comment: Excellent Jite. Thanks alot. That was really really helpfull